# Using CreateJS to apply an alpha tween to a drawn line

Tags: html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

I'm trying to take a users mouse/touch drawn line and then have it alpha fade out the result using a tween. The problem is when cap and joint style are set to rounded then joint point fades behind the rest of the line. It looks fine when set to miter or bevel.

What I want is a smooth solid fade of the shape. Any ideas?

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcfarljw/ZNGK2/**

Function for drawing the line based on user input:

```
function handleMouseMove(event) {
var midPt = new createjs.Point(oldPt.x + stage.mouseX >> 1, oldPt.y + stage.mouseY >> 1);

drawingCanvas.graphics.setStrokeStyle(stroke, 'round', 'round').beginStroke(color).moveTo(midPt.x, midPt.y).curveTo(oldPt.x, oldPt.y, oldMidPt.x, oldMidPt.y);

oldPt.x = stage.mouseX;
oldPt.y = stage.mouseY;

oldMidPt.x = midPt.x;
oldMidPt.y = midPt.y;

stage.update();
```

}

Tween applied to the shape after line is finished:

```
createjs.Tween.get(drawingCanvas).to({
    alpha: 0
}, 2000).call(function() {
    drawingCanvas.alpha = 1;
    drawingCanvas.graphics.clear();
});
```

[image: alpha tweened touch input line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to [cache the whole shape](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_cache) before fading it out. See the updates I have made to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNGK2/3/). Mainly, take a look at line 52 on the handleMouseUp event.

```
drawingCanvas.cache(0, 0, 800, 800);
```

Then, when your fade is complete. Make sure to uncache before showing the object again. Otherwise your graphics.clear() won't work.

```
drawingCanvas.uncache();
```

Comment: That's great and exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Didn't think about caching it first.